# Java String Tokenizing for a Programming Language Parser

Tags: java, string, tokenize, stringtokenizer

A few months ago, I thought it would be cool to make my own programming language. So I did. I named it [Pogo](https://github.com/nrubin29/Pogo). If you look at the code, you'll see a ton of `String#split`. Here's some pseudocode that describes how I parse a method header:

Given `method public void main()`, I look to see if `String#startsWith("method")`. If so, I `String#split(" ")` and parse the second word (public) to a visibility. I treat the third word (void) as the return type, and check to see if it's a primitive or class. Finally, I treat the last word as the name and parse any method parameters properly.

This method works, but I know it's wrong. You're supposed to tokenize everything and handle it like that. However, I don't quite understand how that would work. I know I'd use Java's `StringTokenizer`, but how would I parse a method header? Given `method public void main()`, the first token would be method. I'd know I'm working with a method, but I can't instantiate my `Method` class because I don't have all the information yet. It seems like I'd have to declare a loop for the `StringTokenizer` and have tons of variables outside of it, which almost seems worse than what I have now.

**tl;dr**: How should I use String tokenization to parse a custom programming language. I'm not really looking for code, more like pseudocode or ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but remember there is no right and wrong.

Comment: @immibis I know that my solution works, but I also know that any good programming language doesn't parse code the way I do.

Comment: @immibis I see what you mean and I wasn't trying to insult you or anything. I've had the current system for awhile and have been looking for ways to improve it so that I can add more advanced syntax to the language. I have dreams of object-oriented methods and pluggable reserved words.

Comment: Looking through examples of Pogo I see a main method being declared as `method main:void`, but your question has `method public void main()`. Which is correct?

Comment: @jdphenix If you are looking at the wiki, those examples are old. I noted on the main page that I redid a lot in the language and that I'd have to update the wiki. `method public void main()` is correct.

Comment: Gotcha - I saw the page tagged [OLD] and I thought that was the documentation that was out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I want to start by pointing out that whatever you are doing is not necessarily a "wrong" way, and there's isn't really a "right" way of doing this.*

---

> Given method public void main(), the first token would be method. I'd know I'm working with a method, but I can't instantiate my Method class because I don't have all the information yet.

Yes, that's correct. You're on the right track for parsing a method declaration.

You can write a grammar for method declaration, for example (this is based on your Pogo implementation and your question here):

```
MethodDeclaration: 
    "method" Access ReturnType Name
Access:
    "public"
    "private"
    "protected"
Return:
    "void"
    "integer"
    "string"
Name:
    alphabetic-only-string
```

And we would step through this like this:

1. Parsing comes upon `method`,
2. Is the next token a valid access modifier?
3. Is the next token a valid return type?
4. Is the next token a valid name?
5. If yes to all, parse the method.

Here is such an implementation. I do not guarantee it to be bug free. I purposefully miss many Java "good coding practices", for the sake of brevity.

```
class Method { 
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Method [access=" + access + ", type=" + type + ", name=" + name
                + "]";
    }

    Access access; 
    ReturnType type; 
    String name;

    public Method (Access access, ReturnType type, String name) { 
        this.access = access; 
        this.type = type; 
        this.name = name;
    }
}

enum Access {
    Public("public"), 
    Private("private"), 
    Protected("protected");

    private String token;

    Access(String token) { 
        this.token = token; 
    }

    String token() { return token; }
}

enum ReturnType { 
    Void("void"), 
    Integer("integer"), 
    String("string");

    private String token;

    ReturnType(String token) { 
        this.token = token; 
    }

    String token() { return token; }
}

class InvalidCodeException extends Exception {
    private final String message; 

    public InvalidCodeException(String string, Object... params) {
        message = String.format(string, params);
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() { 
        return message; 
    }
}

public class MethodParse {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidCodeException { 
        System.out.println(methodDeclaration());
    }

    static String tokens = "method public void main()";  
    static StreamTokenizer stream = new StreamTokenizer(new StringReader(tokens));

    static String nameDeclaration() throws IOException, InvalidCodeException { 
        stream.nextToken();
        for (char c : stream.sval.toCharArray()) { 
            if (Character.getType(c) != Character.UPPERCASE_LETTER && 
                Character.getType(c) != Character.LOWERCASE_LETTER) { 
                throw new InvalidCodeException("name expected, found %s", stream.sval);
            }
        }
        return stream.sval;
    }

    static ReturnType returnTypeDeclaration() throws IOException, InvalidCodeException { 
        stream.nextToken();
        for (ReturnType rt : ReturnType.values()) {
            if (rt.token().equals(stream.sval)) {
                return rt; 
            }
        }
        throw new InvalidCodeException("access modifier expected, found %s", stream.sval);
    }

    static Access accessDeclaration() throws IOException, InvalidCodeException { 
        stream.nextToken();
        for (Access a : Access.values()) {
            if (a.token().equals(stream.sval)) {
                return a; 
            }
        }
        throw new InvalidCodeException("access modifier expected, found %s", stream.sval);
    }

    static Method methodDeclaration() throws IOException, InvalidCodeException {
        stream.nextToken(); 

        if (!stream.sval.equals("method")) { 
            throw new InvalidCodeException("method expected, found %s", stream.sval); 
        }

        return new Method(accessDeclaration(), returnTypeDeclaration(), nameDeclaration());
    }
}
```

Designing the parsing of different parts of Pogo will following a similar thought process.

1. Design a grammar,
2. Step through how the language would be parsed,
3. write code.

There is an excellent walk-through of implementing a math expression parser in Bjarne Stroustrup's *Programming, Principles and Practice Using C++*. It would be reasonable to adapt it to Java and use the guidelines there to implement other kinds of expression parsers, *like those for programming languages*.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I took your idea and decided to rewrite the Pogo parser to use an abstract Parser superclass for each grammar (class, method, etc). I noticed that you forked the repo. If you merge(?) the latest push I made, you'll see how I got started.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is not really a tokenising problem. In a fairly standard parser there are distinct stages, tokenising - breaking your input up into chunks ("method",""public","void","main","(",")") and parsing - taking the list of tokens and combining them according to the grammar of the language. It makes sense to keep these two separate don't try to do any grammar analysis in the tokenising stage.

Programming languages are complex beast and parsing is a specialised task, there are special tools to do such a task. In the unix/C world there is lex/flex for tokenising and yacc/bison for parsing. In java there is JavaCC which I've used and probably many others. You will find it much easier to use these tool which generally generate code for the parser. This is especially worthwhile at the early stages when your grammar is flexible. It will be much easier to change a grammar definition file that try and debug some complex hand written code.

Sometimes at a very late stage compilers will move to hand written code for the parser but these are complex state machines requiring a lot of theory to get right.